# What does seasonality of 1 mean?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

What does having a seasonality of 1 mean?

Suppose I have hourly data and I define the seasonality to be 1, does that mean the data will be dealt with as if there is no seasonality?

Comment: We can't tell from this which software you are using or how you are declaring your time series to that software. Please rewrite the question to be informative and add appropriate tags.

Comment: What I mean is that in an hourly data, the daily seasonality is given by 24. In monthly data, the seasonality is 12. So what does the value of 1 imply?

Comment: At a very wild guess, no periodicity at all. Seasonality usually means variations within year; other kinds of periodicity are best named informatively. My previous comment still applies: this appears to be about how some software treats your data, and saying nothing about the software cannot help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a time series with a number of cycles (e.g. multiple years with each 12 months) then the seasonality indicates for each month how the trend should be adjusted. In this context it would mean that for a specific period you need to adjust your trend with 1 to get the right forecast. That said, I find this a bit of a weird question and it offers too little context to write any meaningful answer.

I would suggest that you have a look at the following text as the authors of this text offer a good insight into time series and the associated forecasting techniques. Happy reading: http://otexts.com/fpp/6/

Comment: I don't think you and the original poster are talking about the same thing. I think the OP is asking about the seasonal period, not the size of a coefficient.